# Understanding FAT16

Tags: filesystems, fat, fat16

I'm developing a flash based USB mass storage device with `FAT16` file system.
It's working properly, however I have difficulties understanding what's happening on the FAT segments.

When I begin, I have a single file, 56 bytes long on the root directory, it's 32bits long and the data is stored on the 2nd cluster (the 0 and the 1 can't be used in FAT).

if I look at the memory dump of the FAT segment I see:

```
f8 ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00... zeros until the end
```

As I understand, the last 0xFFFF means that this cluster is the last cluster in the chain for this file.

so far so good.

**But**... when I extend the size of the actual file to 4,032 bytes , the FAT segment turn into

```
f8 ff ff 00 f0 ff 05 60 00 07 f0 ff 00 00 00 00 00... zeros until the end
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here ?

I see several things I can't explain:

**1. why does the 4 system reserved bytes change ?**

**2. I can't see any 0xFFFF which means, there isn't an end to the cluster chain ?**

If it helps anyone, the block size is 512 bytes, the file system is formatted 2 segments per cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures it was FAT12 and not FAT16 I was working with.

FAT12-16 distinguished by the number of clusters, not the string that's written in the boot sector.